# What expression returns data defined color from a color field eg: (30 50 40 10) using color_cmyk

Tags: qgis, expression, color, geology

I have a geology plan with a base color field. I need to write an expression in the data defined color option using "color_cmyk" command. I can not seem to get the expression written correctly. The data is in the format "30 80 20 10".

Answer (score 2):

The following expression isolates the numbers with regular expressions and then converts it to a number before passing it to the color_cmyk script

```
color_cmyk( 
  format_number( regexp_substr( "color", '(\\d+)' ), 0 ),
  format_number( regexp_substr( "color", '\\d+ (\\d+)' ), 0 ),
  format_number( regexp_substr( "color", '\\d+ \\d+ (\\d+)' ), 0 ),
  format_number( regexp_substr( "color", '\\d+ \\d+ \\d+ (\\d+)' ), 0 )
)
```

There may be more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Use this expression, where `"color"` stands for the field containing the input string - instead of it, you could directly use the input string there:

```
eval ('color_cmyk (' || array_to_string (string_to_array ("color", ' '))  || ')')
```

Input `30 80 20 10` -> output: `'161,46,184'`

---

**How it works:**

The expression converts the string to an array and back to a string, in this way replacing the spaces by commas. Thes comma separated values are the arguments of the `color_cmyk()` function. To work, concatenate these separate parts and than convert this string to a function with `eval()`.